# Can't update to 16 react (jscodeshift -t --parser=flow)

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, jscodeshift

Then I use `jscodeshift -t --parser=flow` - I Have a error "Cannot read property 'process' of undefined". Project with Flow. The attempt with downgrade flow-parser was unsuccessful